# Error parsing argv as char*

Tags: c++, argv

I want to read argv[1] as char* so this is what I do

```
    using namespace std;
    const char *myarg = NULL;

void Plots(char* file);

int main( int size_t argc, char* argv[] ) {

        myarg = argv[1];
        cout<<"  this is a test "<<argv[1]<<endl;
        Plots(argv);
}


void Plots(char* fileList){

    cout<< argument passed correctly "<<endl;
            }

    }
```

However, when executing I get

```
Error: Function Plot() is not defined in current scope  :0:
```

Comment: `Plot` != `Plots`.

Comment: `"<<` is strangely highlighted, don't you think?

Comment: this does not work - still the same....

Answer (score 4):

`argv` is a `char *[]`, which for all practical purposes is `char **`.

You declared

```
void Plots(char * file);
```

The parameter to `Plots()` is a `char *`.

```
Plots(argv);
```

This attempts to pass a `char **` to a function that takes `char *` as a parameter.

Additionally, although you declared

```
void Plots(char * file);
```

but then you went ahead and defined

```
void Plot(char* fileList)
```

Furthermore:

```
cout<< argument passed correctly "<<endl;
```

There's a quote missing here.

So, there's three different bugs here.

Comment: thanks - the typo in the quote was fixed . can you suggest how to make it work ie with a correct definition of Plots etc ?

Comment: @Just_Newbie Change the `Plots()` signature to `void Plots(char ** fileList);` The last pointer from the list is a `nullptr`.

Comment: It depends on what do you want to do. Do you need to pass a `char *` or a `char **`? Only you know how you make your own code work.

Comment: I only need to pass the argv as char *. Would be obliged if you could edit the initial code with the correct one.

Comment: You cannot "pass the argv" as `char *` because argv is a `char **`. Perhaps you need to pass argv[0], which would be a `char *`. Or maybe argv[1]. Who knows. Only you know what you want to do.